# Partitioning HD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have a 160GB hard drive, and it is partitioned as follows:
35.6 GB for C:
113 GB for D:

Respectively, in that order in HD.

I would like to take some space from D: to C: in order to leave them both with the same space. The same intention is to increase the C: drive that Windows 7 is claiming space.

I've tried several software partitioning, including the one that comes natively in Windows 7. They complain that the space must be continuous to be added to a unit.

Can anyone give me a hint for me to do what I want?

Comment: You will need 3rd party partition software to get it done, as always make full backups of your data Before you change partition structure. Install and Make the bootable disc before you modify partitions....http://www.paragon-software.com/home/pm-express/

Comment: I've tried "Paragaon Partition Manager", but can not resize my partition, it also.

Comment: Operation failed, The restart operation, that has been requested now, cannot be perfomed now because you are under a 64-bit system. Use the system recovery disc boot.

Comment: I'm trying to install a 64bit version to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to defragment both of your partitions to move the files to the beginning of the partition.  When that is complete, you will need to use a 3rd party tool to do the trick.

I prefer the Linux GParted software that you can download and make a live CD out of.  I have had good luck doing this in the past.

http://gparted.sourceforge.net/

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I managed to move the partition  and everything else. Thanks anyway.